# How to display console messages to the user?

Tags: javascript, browser, console

Sometimes there occurs some errors and I want to display these console messages to the users so that when they take screenshot I can see the error message (from the framework I use or console.log I wrote, or normal JavaScriprt errors). Is it possible?

Simply I want to display all the messages in console to the user.

Comment: AFAIU, eventually you need to see console logs from the user's browser yourself. In this case I would suggest you to use [JS LogFlush](https://github.com/hindmost/jslogflush) (plug!). It is an integrated JavaScript logging tool which allows you to save all `console.log` output in a file on your server. Note that this requires php script placed on a web server.

Comment: Well then return it as an error message displayed to the user, not a console message. Ideally in a production environment you shouldn't send anything to console.log, unless being in some kind of debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

May this helps you; I use below code to show "Errors" on new window instead of inspect element (console log)..

```
//Handle Ajax Error
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, jqXHR,ajaxSettings, thrownError){
        openErrorWindow(jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });

//Handle document Error - example - function undefined
    window.onerror = function(e) {
        openErrorWindow(e);
        console.log(e);
    };

//Open new window with error message
    function openErrorWindow(message){
        var newwindow = window.open('');
        newwindow.document.writeln('<title>Console Error</title>');
        newwindow.document.writeln(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override console.log :

```
var oldlog = console.log

// or console.oldlog = console.log

console.log = function() { 
    alert(JSON.stringify(arguments))
}
```

This is a simple example you can start with.

Perhaps you would also like to override other console functions e.g. console.error